# How to add a button for each animation?

Tags: javascript

I have the code that when the button is pressed play a different animation, but I would like to assign each animation to a certain button, how would I change it? Could i just use array.push(value)?

Javascript:

```
const nextButtonComponent = () => ({
  init() {
    const animationList = ['idle', 'pockets', 'hiphop', 'chicken']

    const model = document.getElementById('model')
    const nextButton = document.getElementById('nextbutton')

    nextButton.style.display = 'block'

    let idx = 1  // Start with the 2nd animation because the model starts with idle animation
    const nextAnimation = () => {
      model.setAttribute('animation-mixer', {
        clip: animationList[idx],
        loop: 'repeat',
        crossFadeDuration: 0.4,
      })
      idx = (idx + 1) % animationList.length
    }
    nextButton.onclick = nextAnimation  // Switch to the next animation when the button is pressed.
  },
})

export {nextButtonComponent}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal html the javascript is targeted at?

Answer (score 0):

I like delegation. Can you try this one, I assume all buttons are in a container with `id="buttonsContainer"` but since you did not post any HTML, it is a guess and you need to change this or add the container

```js
const model = document.getElementById('model');
const animationList = ['idle', 'pockets', 'hiphop', 'chicken'];
const animationButtonsComponent = () => ({
  init() {
    const buttonsContainer= document.getElementById('buttonsContainer');
    buttonsContainer.innerHTML = animationList
      .map((animation, idx) => `<button class="animationButton" data-animation="${animation}">${animation}</button>`).join('');

    // Event delegation for buttons inside the container
    buttonsContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const tgt = e.target.closest("button.animationButton");
      if (!tgt) return
      const animation = tgt.dataset.animation;
      model.setAttribute('animation-mixer', {
        clip: animation,
        loop: 'repeat',
        crossFadeDuration: 0.4,
      });
    });
  },
});

export { animationButtonsComponent };
```